# copy png image to clipboard in windows from commandline preserving transparency

Tags: command-line, clipboard

I have tried nircmd.exe for this, it turns transparency to black. I have also tired XnView, which turns transparency to white.

Don't know how to do this with ImageMagick either, I thought that `convert file.png png:- | clip` would work, but it looks like it gives me text on my clip like `ëPNG...`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need "paste" image to program.

You can simulate Windows Explorer copy command with [CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/). After download and run [CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/), type this command:

```
copyq.exe copy text/uri-list file:///C:/testdir/file.png
```

C:/testdir/file.png - path to image. Should be used forward slash **/**

---

Also you can give directly full path file.png to program.

```
"C:\Program Files\paint.net\PaintDotNet.exe" "C:\testdir\file.png"
```

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ/wiki/Advanced-Usage) also shown how copy raw data to clipboard. But i not sure how do it in Windows.